# PHP Functions - Returning arguments to mulitple variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to perform two calculations in one function and return the values of both calculations to seperate variables. I think i have everything setup nearly correct but i'm getting an error message which i'll post after the code. I could easily write two functions to do what I want but i'd rather have it all in one function since the function is initiated by the click of one button.

```
function sg_gc1($gv_1, $g_1) {
        $gv_1 = $gv_1 - 1;
    Return $gv_1;

        $g_1 = $g_1 + 20;
    Return $g_1;
}


// This second part in my code is mostly irrelevant to my question but it helps paint  the picture.

if (isset($_POST['Calculate']) && ($_SESSION['gv_1'] != 0) ) {
    $_SESSION['gv_1'] = sg_gc1($_SESSION['gv_1']); // line 55
    $_SESSION['g_1'] = sg_gc1($_SESSION['g_1']);  // line 56

}  // This statement assigns the new calculated values to my existing session variables and it worked just fine before i tried adding in the second argument
```

Warning: Missing argument 2 for sg_gc1(), called in F:PATH on line 55 and defined in F:PATH on line 6
Warning: Missing argument 2 for sg_gc1(), called in F:PATH on line 56 and defined in F:PATH on line 6

So the error is happening inside the function which leads me to believe the function is not set up properly for two arguments. It works just fine with 1 argument if i were to remove all the g_1 parameters.

Comment: you call sg_gc1() (twice) with only one argument when it expects 2

Comment: `return` exists the function, so only the first one will ever run.

Comment: consider returning an array `return array($gv_1,$g_1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call function like this, because your function accepts two arguments and you are passing only one.

```
sg_gc1($_SESSION['gv_1'],$_SESSION['g_1']);
```

and in function you have to return like below. Your second return would never get executed.

```
function sg_gc1($gv_1, $g_1) {
    $gv_1 = $gv_1 - 1;
    $g_1 = $g_1 + 20;
    return array($gv_1,$g_1);
}
```

Calling function part

```
if (isset($_POST['Calculate']) && ($_SESSION['gv_1'] != 0) ) {

 list($_SESSION['gv_1'],$_SESSION['g_1']) = sg_gc1($_SESSION['gv_1'],$_SESSION['g_1']);
 echo $_SESSION['gv_1']."--".$_SESSION['g_1'];//for checking purpose
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return two variables in a function. Return an array instead:

```
function sg_gc1($gv_1, $g_1) {
    $gv_1 = $gv_1 - 1;
    $g_1 = $g_1 + 20;
    return array($gv_1, $g_1);
}
```

Now to retrieve the values, you can simply access the array indices:

```
$arr = sg_gc1($_SESSION['gv_1'], $_SESSION['g_1']);
$gv_1 = $arr[0];
$g_1 = $arr[1];
```

Or you could use the [`list`](http://php.net/list) construct to do it in one line:

```
list($gv_1, $g_1) = sg_gc1($_SESSION['gv_1'], $_SESSION['g_1']);
```